# Redirect specific urls of a domain, while leaving others unaffected

Tags: windows-7, nginx, redirect, hosts

I'm currently trying to replace some images by a foreign flash application requested from an extern cdn. Therefore I modified my etc/hosts with the line

```
127.0.0.1 static.cdn.example.com
```

Now I'm running a nginx webserver, to proxy all calls to the cdn. The images I want to replace are routed to local files and all other should be passed to the original cdn. My nginx configuration looks like this

```
location /flash {
    rewrite ^.*image1.png /image1.png;
    rewrite ^.*image2.png /image2.png;
    rewrite ^.*image3.png /image3.png;
    proxy_pass http://static.cdn.example.com;
}
```

The problem is, that my hosts-entry prevent nginx from resolving the url and it ends in a infinite redirection loop. I tried to lookup the cdn-ip by myself, but that didn't worked. What can I do or what am I doing wrong? Are there easier ways to intercept specific urls?

I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`resolver`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#resolver) parameter. Nginx will use the resolver DNS servers directly, skipping `/etc/hosts`.

```
location /flash {
    resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4;
    rewrite ^.*image1.png /image1.png;
    rewrite ^.*image2.png /image2.png;
    rewrite ^.*image3.png /image3.png;
    proxy_pass http://static.cdn.example.com;
}
```

Here I am setting the DNS to [Google's public DNS servers](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/), but feel free to use whichever ones you want.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be the solution I am looking for. Unfortunately, every time I try to use the resolver nginx throws the error `[error] 2816#1784: *9210 maximum number of descriptors supported by select() is 1024 while connecting to upstream`. Do you have any ideas, where that come from?

Comment: I solved it now with the firefox plugin FoxyProxy to redirect only the specific urls to the nginx-server, which returns the local files. Not the best way, but it works :)